# Difference between Test mode and Functional mode in JTAG

Tags: jtag

Hi while reading the datasheet for an ethernet controller chip, I came across the terms *functional mode* and *test mode* in relation to JTAG.

Can someone kindly explain these terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functional Mode: The inner logic is connected to the externally visible pins; the device works as it is intended to. If a sample/preload instruction is issued via JTAG, it is possible to sample the current pin states.

Test Mode: The inner logic is disconnected from the pins and pins are driven/read by the boundary scan logic only. This is usually referred to as EXTEST.

I find the explanations from XJTAG very user friendly, so you might want to check those out: http://www.xjtag.com/support-jtag/jtag-technical-guide.php